# How can i get UTC +1 from React DatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker, utc, gettime

I am using React DatePicker to get the date and time for a booking.

Everything seems to work, i get the right date and it gets sent to the database but if i select let's say 10:30 as time, what i get to the database is 9:30, because apparently UTC is being used but i am in UTC + 1.

I tried the following to convert to UTC + 1 but both methods didn't work. What else can i try?

First method:

```
  const date1 = new Date()
  const inc = 1000 * 60 * 60 // an hour

  const _date = new Date(date1)

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
    new Date( _date.getTime() + inc )
   );
```

Second method:

```
function addHoursToDate(date, hours) {
    return new Date(new Date(date).setHours(date.getHours() + hours));
  }
  const myDate = new Date();
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
    addHoursToDate(myDate, 1 )
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the date in your database as milliseconds since the Unix Epoch. In this way, you can show the right date in your client without worry about the timezone.

```
const yourDate = new Date();
const millisSinceUnixEpoch = yourDate.getTime();

...save on db...

...get from db...

const yourDate = new Date(millisSinceUnixEpochFromDb);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this: `const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());`  and this: `const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date.getTime;` and also this:  `const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date(new Date().getTime));` which seems to be the same thing you are suggesting (as per https://currentmillis.com/), but i get the following error from date-fns : RangeError: Invalid time value